# Viewing a PDF with QLViewController in a WebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

Basically, I want to click a button in my web view that will download a PDF from a remote website and display it with a close/back button. I'm using QLViewController so people can pinch-zoom the PDF, and I'm using PhoneGap 3.0 with XCode 5 to code it.

Here's the code for my plugin that will show the new view with the back button but I can't seem to get the PDF to show.  Any ideas?

```
#import "PDFViewer.h"
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>

@implementation PDFViewer

- (void)loadRemotePdf:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;
    NSString *website = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filename = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:1];

    if (website != nil && [website length] > 0) {

        CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        CGSize screenSize = rect.size;
        UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

        UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,screenSize.width,screenSize.height)];
        webView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
        [webView canGoBack];
        webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

//        NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:website];
//        NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myUrl];

//        [webView loadRequest:myRequest];

//        [window addSubview: webView];

        NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:website];
        NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        if ( urlData )
        {
            NSArray   *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

            filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, filename];
            [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

            // Create test view controller
            QLPreviewController *previewer = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
            previewer.dataSource = self;
            previewer.delegate = self;

            // Create navigation controller
            UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:previewer];

            [window addSubview: [nav view]];
            [window makeKeyAndVisible];
        }


        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
    }
    else {
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR];

    }

    // return result
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
}

#pragma mark - QLPreviewControllerDataSource
- (NSInteger)numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController:(QLPreviewController *)controller {
    return 1;
}

- (id <QLPreviewItem>) previewController: (QLPreviewController *) controller previewItemAtIndex: (NSInteger) index;
{
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: filePath];
    return fileURL;
}
@end
```

Comment: Only use the [tag:xcode] tag for questions about the IDE itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done with the UIWebView.

If you are trying to display a PDF file residing on a server somewhere, you can simple load it to your web view directly:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];

NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/UIWebView_Class.pdf"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView release];
```

**//Or if you have a PDF file bundled with your application (in this example named "document.pdf"):**

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"document" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView release];
```

Comment: I've tried to do it this way at first (it's commented out above) but it lacks zoom in/out and doesn't show a close button.  Many people suggest using the QLPreviewController to get those capabilities. So basically I'm trying to understand how I can get the PDF to show over the web view and then close to go back to it.